# powershell extract a range of text from a string as one output

Tags: string, range

how can i extract the last 5 indices from `yyyyMMdd`?

meaning i need `yMMdd`

ie. todays date is `20141127`, and i need to extract the index range of 3 through 8 so i can create a variable that contains `41127`

i tried:

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")[3..8]
```

but it gives me the following output:

```
PS > 4  
PS > 1  
PS > 1  
PS > 2  
PS > 7
```

i need (in one line in order to create variable):

```
PS > 41127
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work for your scenario

```
$untrimmedDate = Get-Date -format "yMMdd"
$trimmedDate = $untrimmedDate.Substring(1)
```

See the technet articles on [Get-Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx) and [Substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx) as references

Comment: thank you sir, im using now `$dte = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyMMdd")).Substring(1)`